# How to add more text data ( >16MB) in a existing field onto azure search index

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

We need to add 130 MB data into a searchable string field in the index,

However API has limit of 16 MB as mentioned into limit page listed below, besides, since its per call it;

"....Primitive collection example: If the document contains a field "Tags" of type Collection(Edm.String) with value ["budget"], and you execute a merge with value ["economy", "pool"] for "Tags", the final value of the "Tags" field will be ["economy", "pool"]. It will not be ["budget", "economy", "pool"]...."

[Azure search limits](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-limits-quotas-capacity#:%7E:text=Document%20size%20limits%20per%20API,API%20is%20approximately%2016%20megabytes.)

**Question**: Can I divide the data across multiple calls and upload full 130 MB data into a single index document? as that data belong to one record/entity on our index.

PS: merge at below link seems performing the replace instead of addition

[Index Data Upload](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/addupdate-or-delete-documents)

Answer (score 1):

It is correct that the limit to a specific field for a single document in an Azure Cognitive Search index is 16MB.  It is important to note however, that this is the size of the text that is put into the field and not of of the original document (if you are using documents).  For example, you might have a 130 MB PDF, but the actual text is only a few MB which would fit.

As for going beyond that, I would be interested in why you might want to do that?  In most cases, if there is actually this much text, it is typically more usable from a search perspective to split the text up into separate search index documents.  For example, if the content was coming from a huge PDF, maybe you index one chapters such that one chapter represents a single document?

Comment: Thanks Liam, in our scenario we capture all the purchase order of a supplier and keeping that into a searchable string field, there are cases where we have thousands of orders for few supplier and text size is more then 130MB. In case to reduce the size if I just capture the distinct keywords then I could loose the frequency of the words, stop words reduction is reducing the size only by few MBs.

Comment: So just to confirm 16MB limit is for document size? as documents only talks about size per call limit i.e. 16 MB

Comment: That is the limit, 16MB per document  (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-limits-quotas-capacity#document-limits). If you have a large document (16MB) you can only send one document per call.

Comment: Thanks Luis, As per doc "Document size limits per API call" does it also means size of the document on the index, regardless of API ?   Can I not use merge for updated/replace content of the document?

Comment: I would suggest creating each purchase order as a separate document. 

It sounds like you want to append each new purchase order to a single field in a single record. What is the use case for such an approach? If you instead index each purchase order separately, you have a future-proof design that will scale.

Comment: There are two index  Dan, we have first on which search is performed and second used for pulling related data for display purpose (it  has individual purchase order data); Now, first index on which search is performed hold supplier plus purchase order text so that my search get influenced by purchase order text as well e.g. if more orders with specific keyword if that keyword I search that particular supplier should get more weightage and come into top in search.